# Can I award back my bounty points or decrease the bounty time period?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I have set a question bounty. Now I want to get back my bounty points and decrease the time period of bounty.

Where are the options for it? Does anybody have an idea about it?

Comment: The whole point of a bounty is to give more attention to your question.  You have achieved that, so why should you get your bounty back?

Comment: I'm rolling back this question, since it got edited into something completely different. @Govind, if you want to ask a new and different question, ask it as an entirely new question.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot reclaim reputation given out in a bounty.

All you can do is award it - once awarded, the bounty will be finished.

There is much more detail in [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)